# Get category and sub-category name in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a `TBLCATEGORIES` and a `TBLPRODUCTS` table. I want to get the category and sub-category name on the *Products.aspx* page with using joins:

[image: Table]

The code below isn't working correctly:

```
DataTable dtProducts = system.GetDataTable(@"Select b.CategoryName,  
        a.* from TBLPRODUCTS a LEFT JOIN TBLCATEGORIES b ON 
        (A.SubCategoryID=B.CategoryID) order by a.ProductID desc");
if (dtProducts.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    CollectionPager1.DataSource = dtProducts.DefaultView;
    CollectionPager1.BindToControl = rpProducts;

    rpProducts.DataSource = CollectionPager1.DataSourcePaged;
    rpProducts.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: _isn't working correctly_ could you elaborate a bit this statement?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need two joins:

```
Select p.*, c.CategoryName, sc.CategoryName as SubCategoryName
from TBLPRODUCTS p left join
     TBLCATEGORIES c
     on p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId left join
     TBLCATEGORIES sc
     on c.SubCategoryId = sc.CateogryId
order by p.ProductID desc;
```

Comment: @Shkupjane we can't help with "not working correctly". Your question can't be answered in its current form.  Please read [ask] and explain **how** it's not working. Explain what you expect to see and what actually happens.